# Transition from large to small image smooth animation - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a login-page where I want the transition of the logo from large to small (and back) to be smoother. As it is now, it just pops between the two.

When the keyboard opens, I would like the logo to animate to the smaller position, instead of just instantly changing.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: AppColors.yellowLight,
      // appBar: MainAppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 90),
                  child: Image(
                    image: ExactAssetImage('assets/icons/app_logo.png'),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0
                        ? size.height * 0.3
                        : size.height * 0.15,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                  child: MainTextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      labelText: 'E-post',
                      hintText: 'Skriv e-post som abc@epost.no'),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 30, bottom: 30),
                  child: MainTextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    labelText: 'Passord',
                    hintText: 'Skriv inn sikkert passord',
                  ),
                ),
                LoginButton(
                  text: 'Logg inn',
                  isLoading: isLoading,
                  onPressed: _login,
                ),
                // Text('New User? Create Account')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: tried `AnimatedContainer` as a parent for `Image` widget?

Comment: I've tried, but I unfortunately can't seem to get it to work. I'm quite new to all this. But thanks, I'll look deeper into it!

Comment: oooppps, i was wrong: `AnimatedContainer` will not help here :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
 AnimatedContainer(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? 100.0 : 200.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? 100 : 200.0,
              duration:const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
            ),
```

but  **MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom** it won't give you accuracy as if it's real time when changing the keyboard state, so I advice you to use another method to know the current state of the keyboard like the code below

[image]

**you can use this package to listen for keyboard change** [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) here is the code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late StreamSubscription<bool> keyboardSubscription;

  bool _isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();
    // Subscribe
    keyboardSubscription = keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
      if(mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = visible;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
              height: _isVisible ? 100.0 : 200.0,
              width: _isVisible ? 100 : 200.0,
              duration:const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),


            TextFormField(

            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyboardSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**if you don't want to use package for keyboard visibility so you can use this code**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 final FocusNode _myNode =  FocusNode();

  bool _isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  _myNode.addListener(_listener);
  }

  void _listener(){
    if(_myNode.hasFocus){
      // keyboard appeared
      if(mounted){
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = true;
        });
      }
    }else{
      // keyboard dismissed
      if(mounted){
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
              height: _isVisible ? 100.0 : 200.0,
              width: _isVisible ? 100 : 200.0,
              duration:const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),


            TextFormField(
              focusNode: _myNode,

            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myNode.removeListener(_listener);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the second method, but it does not seem like it actually recognizes when the keyboard opens.

Comment: you have two textfield , so did you define two FocusNode and assign the listener to them ? could you please share your code

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that kind of works. At least the animation does. But as it is based on `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0` still, the animation does not start until the keyboard is all the way out of view.

```
            AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0
                ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100)
                : EdgeInsets.only(top: 75, bottom: 10),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0
                ? _height.height * 0.5
                : _height.height * 0.25,
                child: Image(
              image: ExactAssetImage('assets/icons/app_logo.png'),
            ),
          ),
```